# mysql joining three tables with if statements

Tags: mysql, join

I've got a query that's working

```
SELECT *
FROM the_index AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON (t1.activity_id = t2.id) 
LEFT JOIN table_3 AS t3 ON (t1.activity_id = t3.id)
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

that works fine but i want to modify it with some if statements..

```
SELECT *
FROM the_index AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON (t1.activity_id = t2.id)     <---- If t1.event = '2'
LEFT JOIN table_3 AS t3 ON (t1.activity_id = t3.id)     <---- If t1.event = '3'
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

Comment: Explain better. You want to execute one join or the other in relation to `t1.event`'s value?

Answer (score 1):

simply use this:

```
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON (t1.activity_id = t2.id AND t1.event = '2')
LEFT JOIN table_3 AS t3 ON (t1.activity_id = t3.id AND t1.event = '3')
```

Note, that this only works as long as LEFT JOIN is used. Won't work for INNER JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
SELECT *
FROM the_index AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON (t1.activity_id = t2.id AND t1.event = '2')
LEFT JOIN table_3 AS t3 ON (t1.activity_id = t3.id AND t1.event = '3')
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

Caveat: This goes explicitly against MySQL recommendations not to put WHERE-like clauses into a join.

Comment: any reason it is discouraged?